# select max, group by and display other column that's not in group by clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

To keep it short, I have found a tutorial online and followed to the point: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlmax.php

```
SELECT type, MAX(price) FROM products GROUP BY type
```

My question is:
How do I echo which "clothing" is the most expensive (In this case "Blouse")?

**UPDATE:**

---

Sorry guys, my bad. I needed to make myself more clear. What I am looking for is a solution that shows each "name" where they are most expensive:

```
name         type          price

Clothing    Blouse         34.97

Toy       Playstation      89.95

Music     Country Tunes    21.55
```

Comment: Don't you need to `GROUP BY price`, if you want to get the `MAX(price)`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following query:

**Solution #1:**

```
SELECT 
    products.name,
    products.type,
    products.price 
FROM products 
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT type,MAX(price) max_price
    FROM products 
    GROUP BY type  ) t
ON products.type = t.type
AND products.price = t.max_price;
```

[**Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1637b0/1/0)

**Solution #2:**

```
SELECT
    products.name,
    products.type,
    products.price 
FROM
    products
WHERE   (type, price) IN (
        SELECT type, MAX(price) max_price
        FROM products
        GROUP BY type )
```

[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1637b0/2/0)

**EDIT:**

---

**Note:** Both solutions might give you multiple products under same `type` if they share the same `maximum` price.

If you strictly want **at most one** item from each type then you need to **`group by`** again in the last line.

So for both solutions the last line would be:

`GROUP BY products.type, products.price`

[**See Demo of it**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa5471/2/0)

Comment: Please check this query. Look I've added two queries. Both will give you the same result. Check the demo too. @CitronAutobot

Comment: The first solution seems to be working, I have no idea how or why - but thnx alot :)

Comment: If you don't know how `INNER JOIN` works then it would be difficult to understand. That's why I've added the second solution. You need to understand `mysql  IN` for that.

Comment: These queries will both return multiple rows if more than one product has the most expensive price in each type. This might, or might not, be the desired behaviour. For example, if a PlayStation and an XBox both cost £89.95, there will be two rows returned for the "Toy" type.

Comment: Yes you are right @MattRaines. Actually it was my intention. I didn't want to ignore the second item having the same maximum price under the same type. If really want to ignore the second one then need to add another group by as the final line.

Comment: Thanks for  your opinion @MattRaines. Please look at the `EDIT` section of my answer.

Comment: Second solution is more recommendable

Answer (score 0):

This will then order the item by descending price (starting with most expensive) and then display just the first item...

```
SELECT name, MAX(price) 
FROM products 
WHERE type = 'Clothing'
ORDER BY price DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This might return a product that isn't in the "Clothing" type if it's more expensive than the most expensive "Clothing".

Answer (score 0):

You can find the most expensive (highest value) clothing by simply ordering on price and limit the number of records to 1.

```
SELECT name
FROM products 
WHERE type = 'Clothing'
ORDER BY price DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

edit:

As mentioned by Matt, if more than one product has the most expensive price and you want them all. You should include a subquery to fetch more than one.

```
SELECT name
FROM products 
WHERE type = 'Clothing'
AND price = (SELECT MAX(price)
FROM products 
WHERE type = 'Clothing')
```

Comment: This will return only one row (picked arbitrarily) if more than one product has the most expensive price. This might, or might not, be the desired behaviour.

Comment: This is almost the solution. How can I get more than one row?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * 
from product where 
price=(select max(price) 
from product where type='Clothing')
```

this will select the entire row in which the price is the max in clothing type

Comment: This will return multiple rows if more than one product has the most expensive price. This might, or might not, be the desired behaviour.

Comment: You may get other types in your result if those have the same price as the max price of clothing.

Answer (score 0):

With this query you can see all the relations , not just clothing

```
SELECT maxPricesPerType.type,maxPricesPerType.maxPrice,priceTypes.name
    FROM
    (
    SELECT type, MAX(price) maxPrice FROM products GROUP BY type
    ) maxPricesPerType
    INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT type, price,name FROM products GROUP BY type,price
    ) priceTypes
    ON priceTypes.type = maxPricesPerType.type 
    AND priceTypes.price = maxPricesPerType.maxPrice
```

This joins your first array with an array that has unique price-type combinations and displays the name of the max price per type you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

In bigquery, it only allows one to match on one variable in the WHERE clause. Thanks for the great explanation!

```html
SELECT
    name,
    type,
    price 
FROM
    products
WHERE   (price) IN (
        SELECT MAX(price) max_price
        FROM products
        GROUP BY type)
```